# How to make this simple MySQL join select?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the 1st table **registered** and this table contains:

```
uid (int)
email (varchar)
telephone (varchar)
```

It look like this

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ uid   +  email             + telephone       +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ 1    +  david@gmail.com    + 333-111-5555    +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ 2    +  erick@gmail.com    + 333-222-5555    +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ 3    +  james@gmail.com    + 333-333-5555    +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ 4    +  svene@gmail.com    + 333-444-5555    +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ 5    +  simon@gmail.com    + 333-555-5555    +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ 6    +  peter@gmail.com    + 333-666-5555    +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ 7    +  mikka@gmail.com    + 333-777-5555    +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

I have the 2nd table **referrers** and this table contains this columns:

```
id (int)
uid0 (int)
uid1 (int)
```

This second table holds the id which is autoincrement, then uid0 which is the parent user id and uid1 is the user id of the referer

It can have these values for example

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++
+ id   +  uid0 + uid1 +
+++++++++++++++++++++++
+ 1    +  2    +  3   +
+++++++++++++++++++++++
+ 2    +  2    +  5   +
+++++++++++++++++++++++
```

I know how to echo all registered emails and telephones from **registered** table in the foreach loop.

However, I need to join and echo also all referrers (uid1) emails thatbelong to certain user (uid0).

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++
+ id   +  uid0 + uid1 +
+++++++++++++++++++++++
+ 1    +  2    +  3   +
+++++++++++++++++++++++
+ 2    +  2    +  5   +
+++++++++++++++++++++++
+ 3    +  4    +  1   +
+++++++++++++++++++++++
+ 4    +  4    +  6   +
+++++++++++++++++++++++
+ 5    +  4    +  7   +
+++++++++++++++++++++++
```

So, the final echo result will look like this:

```
email                  telephone               referers
erick@gmail.com        333-222-5555            james@gmail.com, simon@gmail.com
svene@gmail.com        333-444-5555            david@gmail.com, peter@gmail.com, mikka@gmail.com
```

How can I do this "threaded" foreach loop?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a couple of style points: although I don't know your exact use case, I imagine user X refers user Y to your service. So, naming-wise, how about "referrer_from" and "referrer_to" - subsequent devs on your code-base will thank you! Also, if you make these two columns a composite primary key (presuming that from+to is unique) then you can drop the id column in the second table.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to do a sub select with [group concat;](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

something like:

```
select r.email, r.telephone from registered as r, 
(SELECT 
       GROUP_CONCAT(r.email)
       FROM registered
       GROUP uid1 where uid0 = r.uid)
```

Comment: hmm, this is not working. I do not see referrers table reference in your sql

Comment: basic inner join can do what I want, i have figured it out finally

Comment: @ joshuabernstein - iner join can't concat data from fields into one string. 
`GROUP_CONCAT([DISTINCT] expr [,expr ...]
             [ORDER BY {unsigned_integer | col_name | expr}
                 [ASC | DESC] [,col_name ...]]
             [SEPARATOR str_val])
`